# How can I send a TCP request with Python, and how does the routing work?

Tags: python, tcp, routes

I managed to finish a program that, in a network, sends data from pc to pc. That's easy as repeaters and everything in one network can route the request to other PCs in the network.

But if I leave my Network and maybe even add a VPN with a few reroutes, how does my data reach the destination?

More importantly, how do I program it? I know that via

`send()`

I can add bytes, flags and an IP address+port, and if I get data from the IP address of a VPN, i cannot just go "yes let's just return it to whenst it came". How do I know what port on the VPN and Router to send it to, how does the VPN know/how do i tell it to forward it to the Router and to what port there, and how do I tell the router to send it to the by me specied port to a specific PC in the Network?

Comment: Routing is controlled by your operating system, not by your application. Your application just needs to know the endpoint it's trying to reach, and the infrastructure should take care of everything in between. There are a variety of books and blogs and other material out there that cover the "how does network routing work" side of things in great detail.

Comment: @larsks so if i enter a port and ip address as destination, what do I put there? the incoming IP address and port? how does the router know that this very message goes to that very PC, unless I'd do manual port forwarding but that's not practical

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: you just need to specify the destination (IP:port). A correctly configured VPN connection should instruct your system to set its IP range and gateway. The setting is either preconfigured or distributed by the VPN server.

It's not really a python question, but networking. Assume we're using TCP/IP, only one NIC attached to your system. Your system is connected to a router or switch, not a peer-to-peer or other network.

Your system's network stack, upon receiving the connection request by python, will only send packets to the default gateway, regardless of its final destination (such information is part of the packet, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).

From this point on, your system has almost no control over the route a packet travels, i.e. which devices to use and which to avoid. Instead, it's defined by the route tables of switches and routers in between. More specifically, the route table defines IP ranges and next hop, e.g.

```
10.0.0.0/8 -> 10.0.0.1  # the next router's IP
1.2.3.4/32 -> a.b.c.d
0.0.0.0/0 -> none
```

Each intermediate device does the same, until the final gateway which your destination is connected to. That one will send the packet to your dest directly, because it knows your dest is within reach.

Common VPN (PPTP, L2TP, IPSec) only adds a virtual NIC, and sets your system's preference, so that corresponding traffic will go through this virtual gateway (instead of the default). But the above still applies.

Comment: Thanks! I am still confused as to "how" the Gateways forward the stuff with only given an IP address though, like are ports unique to a network? aka does the VPN have one port for every connected PC, and has every router one port for every PC? Or how else does the thing travel from the Router to the PC given only IP address and port? and if i enter the Routers IP for a PC, how can I open a special port (like 12345) on my PC and put a listener on there?

Comment: @user11350058 that cannot be explained in one Q&A. Instead, I suggest you read the wiki pages of OSI model and TCP/IP model.